# Does MongoDB not use an index for distincts or counts on an indexed field?

Tags: mongodb

Some queries were suspiciously slow on a relatively small collection (~200K docs), even when the *only* field in the query was an indexed field. e.g. (using the Java driver):

```
eventReportColl.distinct("host").size()
```

takes nearly three seconds and in the shell `coll.distinct("host").length` takes about two, even though *host* is indexed:

```
coll.getIndexes()
```

...

```
{
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
    "host" : 1
  },
  "ns" : "db.event_reports",
  "name" : "host_1"
}
```

Any reason the above query *wouldn't* use the host index? Unfortunately it doesn't appear explain() works on distinct so I can only assume this is the cause. This is in v2.2.4 running on MongoLab. (Also, while two or three seconds may not seem like much, but when you have an API running three or four of these types of queries before returning it adds up...not to mention eventual db size growth). Is there any way to force using an index or otherwise speed up count queries?

Comment: What is the cardinality of the field? Also what MongoLab instance? Are you sure it isn't MongoLab actually slowing you down?

Comment: Regarding cardinality this field has about 80K uniques of the ~200K docs in the collection (all docs have the field in question). The MongoLab instance is the free tier (our dev db) but I don't think that's the problem as we have a paid instance (shared single node small) so I ran the above against that and it was taking 4+ seconds from the driver and 3+ seconds in the shell (not surprising it's taking longer as that's a larger dataset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.runCommand({distinct : 'eventReportColl', key : 'host'})
```

This will give you the query explain. You can check which index is used or how much is 'n', 'nscanned', 'nscannedObjects'. This will help you to understand, why the query is slow.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it is using an index, which is surprising and sad considering how slow it is. Looks like MongoDB may not be suitable to our needs.

Comment: This query will have to scan atleast all the index elements for 'host' index. And this operation can't be that fast ( also depends on how much of the index is cached in RAM ). If the frequency of such queries are high, then better to have a separate counter, calculated during each inserts.